# Updating multiple rows in SQLite with relevant data from the same table

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I have a database that I don't control the source of directly and results in errant '0' entries which mess up generated graphs with these drops to zero. I am able to manipulate the data after the fact and update that database.

It is acceptable that the last known good value can be used instead and so I am trying to make a general query that will remove all the zeros and populate it with the last known value.

Luckily, every entry includes the ID of the last entry and so it is a matter of simply looking back and grabbing it.

I have got very close to a final answer, but instead of updating with the last good value, it just uses the first value over and over again.

#### dummy data

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id INT,r INT,oid INT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(1,10,0);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(2,20,1);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(3,0,2);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(4,40,3);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(5,50,4);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(6,0,5);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(7,70,6);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(8,80,7);

SELECT * FROM tbl;

OUTPUT:
| id|  r |oid|
|---|----|---|
| 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 |
| 3 |  0 | 2 |  ** NEEDS FIXING
| 4 | 40 | 3 |
| 5 | 50 | 4 |
| 6 |  0 | 5 |  ** NEEDS UPDATE
| 7 | 70 | 6 |
| 8 | 80 | 7 |
```

I have worked several queries to get results around what I am after:

#### All zero entries:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE r = 0;

OUTPUT:
| id |  r | oid |
|----|----|-----|
|  3 |  0 |   2 |
|  6 |  0 |   5 |
```

#### Output only the those rows with the preceding good row

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE A in (
  SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE r = 0
  UNION
  SELECT oid FROM tbl WHERE r = 0
  )

OUTPUT:
| id|  r |oid|
|---|----|---|
| 2 | 20 | 1 | 
| 3 |  0 | 2 |
| 5 | 50 | 4 |
| 6 |  0 | 5 |
```

#### Almost works

This is as close as I have got, it does change all the zero's, but it changes them all to the value of the first lookup

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET r = (SELECT r 
         FROM tbl 
         WHERE id in (SELECT oid
                    FROM tbl 
                    WHERE r = 0)
        ) WHERE r = 0 ;

OUTPUT:
| id|  r |oid|
|---|----|---|
| 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 |
| 3 | 20 | 2 |  ** GOOD
| 4 | 40 | 3 |
| 5 | 50 | 4 |
| 6 | 20 | 5 |  ** BAD, should be 50
| 7 | 70 | 6 |
| 8 | 80 | 7 |
```

If it helps, I created this fiddle here that I've been playing with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8afff/1

Comment: Does `oid` always point to a non zero `r`?

Comment: @forpas Thats a very good question, I suppose it is possible, but hasn’t occurred yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data all you have to do is use the correct correlated subquery that returns the value of `r` from the row with `id` equal to the current `oid` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE tbl AS t
SET r = (SELECT tt.r FROM tbl tt WHERE tt.id = t.oid)
WHERE t.r = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c81ca29a6f09122401f096006a2f60df).

Comment: That’s excellent and even allows for the  double (or more) zeros. That’s awesome. Thanks.

Comment: since I asked this question I have not had any issues with the database in question, however today it's started populating with those pesky '0.0' values. Modifying the query to be applicable to my db and this worked perfectly. I'm probably going to work it into a cron job and have it taken care of automagically. Thanks for your help, cheers